# Apache Spark: what happens when one uses a host object value within a worker that has not been broadcasted?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast

Imagine a simple program like this:

```
def main(args: String[]):
 val hostLocalValue = args(0).toInt
 val someRdd = getSomeIntRdd
 val mySum = someRdd
       .map(x => if (x < 0) 1 else hostLocalValue)
       .reduce(_ + _)
 print(mySum)
```

The *map* function which is executed at remote worker uses host-local value without that being broadcasted. How does this work? If THAT works all the time, then what do we need *broadcast()* for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example 'hostLocalValue' will be serialized and send to each worker nodes with 'map' closure. If you have 1000 partitions this variable will be distributed to workers 1000 times. Your variable is Int, so it's ok. But if you variable would be dictionary Map ~100mb, you'll have to send 100 gigs over network.

But if you'll wrap your dictionary in broadcast you have to ship it only once => Benefit!

Comment: Won't this still be a 100gig traffic? I think the answer is "yes, but the 'send' operation would be done only once." Am I right?

Comment: If you have 100mb dictionary, 10 worker nodes, dataset that you want to map over has 1000 partitions (100 for each worker), you'll have to send 100mb * 10 = 1gig of data if you are sending this data from driver node. However for broadcast variable Spark uses high-performant p2p protocol, so it will be much faster. With java serialization you'll have to send serialized clojure with 100mb data 1000 times